# RSS feed items tags not recognized

Tags: drupal, rss, itunes, drupal-views

I'm trying to set up an RSS feed for a podcast. I'm using Drupal and the Views RSS module for this, but I don't think it's relevant or the source of my problems.

My problem is that a feed validator ([CastFeedValidator](http://castfeedvalidator.com/)) isn't recognizing my `<item>` elements. It says I have 0 items, whereas another feed (not for a podcast) on the same site works fine.

The non-working feed (http://www.gentlesite.be/drupal/podcast.xml) has the following `<item>` element (cleaned up for example):

```
<item> 
    <title>Tweede podcast - test</title>
    <link>http://gentlesite.be/drupal/content/tweede-podcast-test</link>
    <description>&lt;p&gt;Enkel zichtbaar voor admin&lt;/p&gt;</description>
    <author>Peter Morlion</author>
    <enclosure url="http://gentlesite.be/drupal/sites/default/files/1000Hz-5sec.mp3" length="30440" type="audio/mpeg" />
    <guid isPermaLink="false">http://gentlesite.be/drupal/content/tweede-podcast-test</guid>
    <pubDate>Mon, 02 Dec 2013 12:37:12 +0100</pubDate>
    <source url="http://gentlesite.be/drupal/podcast.xml">Gentle podcast</source>
    <dc:creator>Peter Morlion</dc:creator>
    <itunes:summary>&lt;p&gt;Enkel zichtbaar voor admin&lt;/p&gt;</itunes:summary>
    <itunes:duration>0:05</itunes:duration>
    <itunes:author>Peter Morlion</itunes:author>
</item>
```

The working feed (http://gentlesite.be/drupal/rss.xml) looks like:

```
<item>
    <title>Resultaten nieuwsbrief enquête</title>
    <link>http://gentlesite.be/drupal/content/resultaten-nieuwsbrief-enqu%C3%AAte</link>
    <description>blablabla</description>
    <pubDate>Tue, 15 Oct 2013 07:49:18 +0000</pubDate>
    <dc:creator>peter.morlion</dc:creator>
    <guid isPermaLink="false">353 at http://gentlesite.be/drupal</guid>
</item>
```

I can't understand why the first wouldn't work. At first I thought it might be because certain tags were missing. But every tag that is in the working feed (title, link, description, pubDate, dc:creator and guid) is in the non-working, and more.

Has anyone experienced something similar and/or know where to start looking?

*update*

For some reason, [validator.org](http://feedvalidator.org/check.cgi?url=http://gentlesite.be/drupal/podcast.xml) isn't seeing the item tags. Firefox and Chrome do, but IE10 doesn't.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well ahem, never mind. After a long search it finally hit me. I am using the Access Control module to hide these items from unauthorized users. The feed validators aren't authorized users so Drupal won't show them. So everything works perfectly. The reason I didn't see them in IE10 was because I wasn't signed in in IE10. I was signed in in FF and Chrome. (slaps forehead)